# python3 EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python-3.x, eoferror

Need help with this, appreciate if someone can try to suggest a fix.

```
$ echo "print('This works fine')"|python3
```

This works fine.

But:

```
$ echo "input('This is NOT working! ')"|python3
```

This is the output received:

> ```
> This is NOT working! Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line
> ```

Comment: Note that you are telling Python to read both the program and input from stdin, but provide only the program.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just want to execute python commands inline from bash. For this task you can use this:

```
python3 -c "input('This also works)"
```

EDIT:
If you want to use the pipe, you can just take the input from bash and pipe it to python, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your name : " name
echo "x='$name';print('My name is', x)"|python3
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have a use-case where I have to pass the file via pipe; however, the code has multiple inputs.  
For reference I have just shared a simple file with only an input statement, as below -   

 `$ more test_input.py`  
  
 `x=input()`  
 `print(x)`  
   
 `$ cat test_input.py |python3`   
  
 `Traceback (most recent call last):`  
   `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`  
 `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

Comment: Does your use case allow for input being read from bash instead? In that case you can do what I showed in my EDIT.

Comment: Thanks @idinu. Unfortunately no. I have everything in the source file i.e. all input variables.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. If you want input from keyboard you can read from bash, otherwise if you have the values in the source file you don't need the `input` function from python, you can pipe the value directly. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Its an interactive program that works based on multiple inputs. The file is sourced on github and I am trying to directly execute same without moving to local system by using `curl -s {file-git-url} | python3`. For now, I am creating a local copy `curl -s {file-git-url} > myprogam.py; python3 myprogram.py`. I was hoping to avoid creating local copy; however, the input function doesn't seem to work via pipe.